# Selecting text input from PHP form using jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have php code that creates a table. For each item on the purchase order a new row is created and populated. The goal is when the purchase order is edited it gets posted back and saved in the database. Everything is working except my jQuery code will only iterate over the first row for however many rows I have. (So if I have three rows it will print the first rows cartid three times.)

Sorry if things look messy.

PHP Code:

```
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($itemsquery)){?>
      <tr class="item-row" id="<?php echo $row['cart_id']?>">
          <td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea><?php echo $row['on0'];?> <?php echo $row['itemname'];?></textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td>
          <td class="description"><textarea class="cartid"><?php echo $row['cart_id'];?></textarea></td>
          <td><textarea class="cost" class="text-input" type="text"><?php echo $row['itemprice'];?></textarea></td>
          <td><textarea class="qty" type="text" name="name"><?php echo $row['quantity'];?></textarea></td>
          <td><span class="price" type="text">$<?php 
        $linecost = $row['quantity'] * $row['itemprice'];
        echo $linecost;?></span></td>
      </tr>
    <?php }?>
```

jQuery statement to see what it has grabbed:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".item-row").change(function() {
$((".cartid")).each(function(){
    row = {
        cartid: $(".cartid").val()
        }  

 alert(row.cartid);
 performAjaxSubmission();
 })
});
```

Comment: i can't see, anywhere in your html a node with class "item-row"

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez - Line 2 of the PHP code.

Comment: sorry, i seem to be blind today.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you just have your selectors mixed up. You are wanting to iterate over each of the rows, but your selector is referencing $(".cartid"), which would always return the first result ever time.

This should fix your problem:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".item-row").change(function() {
    $(".item-row").each(function(){
        var rowContext = $(this);
        var row = {
            cartid: $(".cartid", rowContext).val()
        }  
    alert(row.cartid);
    performAjaxSubmission();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have extra `()` in your `.cartid` selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".item-row").change(function() {
$(".cartid").each(function(){
    row = {
        cartid: $(".cartid").val()
        }  

 alert(row.cartid);
 performAjaxSubmission();
 })
});
```

Also, shoudn't you be looping trough `.item-row` instead of `.cartid`?

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating like this:

```
$(".cartid").each(function(){
row = {
    cartid: $(".cartid").val()
    }
```

Seems like you should be doing

```
$(".cartid").each(function(){
row = {
    cartid: $(this).val()
    }
```

Haven't checked the rest of the code.

**EDIT:**

```
$(".cartid").each(function(){
var cart = $(this);
row = {
    cartid: cart.val()
    }
```